# Any web templates like Joomla for Java websites?

Tags: java, joomla

Are there any web templates like Joomla or Drupal for Java websites? These are made in PHP and cannot be used by Java developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Joomla and Drupal are [CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CMS) systems. **Some** Java equivalents are [Liferay](http://www.liferay.com/) and [OpenCMS](http://www.opencms.org/en/). If you want a templating system, then you might want to look into something like [FreeMarker](http://freemarker.sourceforge.net/).